# How to treat .tpl syntax highlighting like php's syntax highlighting in PHPStorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I use PHPStorm

I need to know how could I treat .tpl files syntax highlighting like that of .php syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to treat `.tpl` files in the same way as `.php` then you will have to re-assign `*.tpl` pattern to **PHP** type in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`

[image]
*(screenshot is from current 2021.2 version)*

The IDE will ask to confirm the removal of that pattern from the standard Smarty file type:

[image]

**P.S.** This is an IDE-wide setting and will affect all projects.

Sadly you cannot have the same pattern to be assigned to a different file type in different projects. Consider using double extension if it's possible: e.g. `*.html.tpl` -- this way you can use such additional pattern assigned to another file type.

Comment: Unfortunately, after a while the *.tpl treating as Smarty templates restores automatically somehow by the IDE itself.

Comment: If this is happening on regular basis -- then submit a ticket to their [Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) (but check for any existing tickets first, as you should normally do).

Comment: I think, it happens because smarty's .tpl association is a part of a core plugin (The one that actually provides PHP support)... Somehow each time its updating (maybe) it also updates its associations. Actually looks like it resets on every IDE start.

Comment: Also in their tracker they have an issue (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13439) which remains untouched for long time, guess since it is marked as duplicate of another, more complex bug.

Comment: Well... I may only suggest to comment on that more complex bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89509 -- maybe it will wake them up somehow..

Answer (score 10):

In PhpStorm configuration settings:

```
 File->Settings->Editor->File Types->php-> + -> add *.tpl
```

[image: PHP storm site settings]

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.